# Keeping track of new primary keys in SQL

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc, transactions

Sorry this is such a long question but it touches on a general issue with databases:

I'm using sqlite/jdbc (in this case), and I'm trying to keep track of the automatic ID's created when I add rows to a table. The database has a main table 'Person' and other tables called 'training' and 'induction'. The idea is that the persons name and other basic details go into the 'Person' table, and that one person many have many 'trainings' and 'inductions'. So, I can look up all the inductions for a given person by SELECT *  FROM INDUCTIONS WHERE PERSON_ID = whatever.

The problem is in creating the database, I have to add a person, then keep track of the  AUTOINCREMENTing ID they got and then create the entries in the other table with that ID as a foreign key:

So

```
int id = 0;    
PreparedStatement prepPerson = conn.prepareStatement("insert into persons values (?, ?);");
prepPerson.setString(2, p.getName());
prepPerson.addBatch();
```

Then

```
PreparedStatement prepInductions = conn.prepareStatement("insert into inductions values (?, ?, ?, ?);");

Then loop over all the inductions {
prepInductions.setInt(2, id);
prepInductions.setString(3, i.getSite());
prepInductions.setString(4, i.getExpiryDate());
prepInductions.addBatch();
}
```

I want the interactions with the data base to be 'atomic', so I want to do

```
prepPerson.executeBatch();
prepInductions.executeBatch();
id++;
```

I realise could instead add the person, do getGeneratedKeys() and then add the inductions with the correct row_id of the new person, but I don't want an exception to occur after the Person is added but before the Inductions are. If that happens then I'll have to roll back time and remove the person.

At the moment as I know I'm creating the database afresh everytime from an external source I'm keeping track of the row_id with a local integer variable, and I know that's living dangerously.

Isn't there a general solution to this sort of situation? Or am I worrying much about the 'atomic' interactions with the database?

Comment: Please clarify a bit why good old transactions don't work for you. AFAIK sqlite supports them and setAutocommit(false) will implicitily start a new transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do use `getGeneratedKeys()` to retrieve the generated ID.

To keep data integrity, use transactions. Normally, JDBC uses 'autoCommit' mode, but in this case you'll need to handle the transaction manually.

Call `.setAutoCommit(false)` on your connection and use `.commit()` and `.rollback()` to commit or discard changes.

(Check the [Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) Javadoc).

Comment: Don't you mean `rollback()` instead of `abort()` (the latter is intended to forcefully close the connection)?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your quick responses. It's clicking now what autocommit is about. I had set it to false before the execute batches and true after them, as per an example, without realising exactly why - I had no `.commit()` at all, yet it still worked. So you can so several `.executeBatch()`es and then one `.commit()` once you're done? That's exactly what I need. Solved.

Comment: @Mike calling `autoCommit(true)` on a connection which is in an active transaction will call `commit()` (as described in the javadoc).

Comment: @Mark. Yep, that seems to work nicely. (Also, just learnt the slow way that you've got to close() you result sets.) Thanks to everyone again.

Answer (score 1):

For scenarios like this the general framework is...

```
Begin A Transaction

 Create your primary entry
 Collect the auto-generated key
 Create your child entries

Commit The Transaction
```

This then allows you to `Rollback the Transaction` if any of the steps fail.

In SQLite, I believe `last_insert_rowid()` can be used to get the auto generated id after your first insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code you've supplied above, but ensure that autocommit is switched off. Then you need to manually commit the transaction once all that person's inductions have been loaded. Or roll it back if you encounter an error.

This is completely atomic.